# How to disable the Tab key in ZK?

Tags: java, zk, zul

How to disable the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key in ZK?
Or, how can I make an event of a <kbd>Tab</kbd> key strike?

Situation needs that nothing should happen when user press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, i. e. the default <kbd>Tab</kbd> key functionality must be disabled.

Comment: Formatting, correcting English

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully like the idea to change established keyboard conventions such as TAB focussing the next input in the tab-order. 
However if a special case requires this behavior you can simply add an event listener to capture and prevent the default action for the tab key (keycode 9):

```
<script>
window.addEventListener(
    'keydown', 
    function(event) {
      if(event.keyCode == 9) event.preventDefault();
    }, 
    {capture: true}
);
</script>
```

Tested on Windows 10: Chrome/FF/Edge

This is not ZK specific and the script can be used on any other html/JS page.

As you were asking "how to do this in ZK" I wonder if you had any ZK problem that makes you want to disable the TAB key.

Robert

Answer (score 0):

We have replaced the default behavior of <kbd>Tab</kbd> in our application as well, because we wanted more control:

- **disabling the focus tabbing** for textfields which allow tab stops to be inserted.
- excluding "unnecessary" fields from the focus tabbing: `readonly` fields, `readonly` comboboxes with hidden combobutton, every radio button of a radiogroup except one (saves the user clicks).
- custom focus tabbing order (using the `tabindex` attribute was not sufficient, as our UI is quite dynamic and can hence have multiple components with the same index across different windows/panels/popups... Hence, we have to treat `tabindex` only in the scope of the closest container parent).

We started with a listener similar to Robert's answer:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        if(event.which === 9) {
            var current = getCurrentlyFocusedComponent();
            if (current.attr('tabindex') && new Number(current.attr('tabindex')) == -1) {
                doNonFocusStuff(current[0], event.shiftKey);                
                event.preventDefault();     
            } else {
                // default focus tabbing
                // or
                // custom focus tabbing with:               
                event.preventDefault();     
            }
        }
    });
});
```

If you want to completly disable <kbd>Tab</kbd> for your page, a simple `event.preventDefault()` will be enough. In the example above you can see that we disable the key only for certain components by setting the the `tabindex = -1`.

Let me know if you are interested in more details of how we do the focus manually or add tab stops, I can share the code.

---

As for sending an event when tab is pressed, you can use this line in the listener I showed above:

```
zAu.send(new zk.Event(zk.$(current), "onTab", {foo: 'some data'}, {toServer: true}));
```

and attach normal listener on the server side:

```
tabbedComponent.addEventListener("onTab", e -> Clients.showNotification("tabbed!"));
```

Read this article for more information on sending custom events to the server: https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Client-side_Reference/Communication/AU_Requests/Client-side_Firing#Fire_Event_to_Widget: